# Query time that I can't understand in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I'm new to this platform, even this is my first question. Sorry for my bad English, I use translate. Let me know if I have used inappropriate language.

my table is like this

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_records (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  data_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  value double NOT NULL,
  record_time datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE tbl_records
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  ADD KEY data_id (data_id),
  ADD KEY record_time (record_time);

ALTER TABLE tbl_records
  MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

my first query
It takes 0.0096 seconds

```
SELECT b.* FROM tbl_records b
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM tbl_records GROUP BY data_id) a
ON a.id=b.id;
```

my second query
Its takes 2.4957 seconds

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM tbl_records GROUP BY data_id;
```

When I do these operations over and over again, the result is similar.
There are 20 million data in the table.
Why is the one with the subquery faster?
Also what I really need is `MAX(record_time)` but

```
SELECT b.* FROM tbl_records b
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(record_time) AS id FROM tbl_records GROUP BY data_id) a
ON a.id=b.id
```

It takes minutes when I run it.

I also need records such as hourly, daily, and monthly. I couldn't see much performance difference between `GROUP BY SUBSTR(record_time,1,10)` or `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record_time,'%Y%m%d')` both take minutes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first query can be simplified to

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_records
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1.
```

The second:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_records
    ORDER BY data_id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

I don't know what the third is trying to do.  This does not make sense:  `MAX(record_time) AS id` -- it is a `DATETIME` that will subsequently be compared to an `INT` in `ON a.id=b.id`.

Another option for turning a `DATETIME` into a `DATE` is simply `DATE(record_time)`.  But it will not be significantly faster.

If the goal is to build daily counts and subtotals, then there is a much better way.  Build and *incrementally* maintain a [*Summary table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .

**(responding to Comment)**

The `GROUP BY` that you have is improper and probably incorrect.  I took the liberty of changing from `id` to `data_id`:

```
SELECT  b.*
    FROM 
        ( SELECT  data_id, MAX(record_time) AS max_time
            FROM  tbl_records
            GROUP BY  data_id
        ) AS a
    FROM  tbl_records AS b
       ON  a.data_id = b.data_id
      AND  a.max_time = b.record_time
```

And have

```
INDEX(data_id, record_time)
```

Can there be duplicate times for one data_id?  To discuss that and other "groupwise-max" queries, see  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: I misspelled MAX(record_time) AS id.
Actually
SELECT b.* FROM tbl_records b
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id,MAX(record_time) AS max_time FROM tbl_records GROUP BY data_id) a
ON a.id=b.id AND a.max_time=b.record_time
shaped.
Maybe I didn't explain my problem fully. I have a table with millions of data that I have collected from hundreds of sources. I want to get the latest data from sources.
LIMIT 1 is not the solution for me

Comment: @MuratYiğit - see my addition